# OpenCV: How to properly copy the inverse of a cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

Let's say I want to create an inverse of a `cv::Mat` in a separate `cv::Mat` container. I do not want the original matrix to be modified. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
cv::Mat mat1 = //...

cv::Mat mat2 = mat1.inv();
```

Does the `inv()` function copy the matrix similar to `clone()`? Because this is exactly how I would clone a `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat mat1 = //...

cv::Mat mat2 = mat1.clone();
```

Also, is it guaranteed that `inv()` will not modify the original matrix?

These are things that I feel like are not made clear in the [documentaion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a039eb3c6740a850696a12519a4b8bfc6)

Comment: IMHO, the doc is quite clear _This means that a temporary matrix inversion object is returned by the method and can be used further as a part of more complex matrix expressions or **can be assigned to a matrix.**_ So yes, you're using it correctly.

Comment: The documentation states that `cv::Mat::inv() const` is `const`.  That is how the documentation is telling you that calling `inv()` on an object will not modify it.